# php wordpress download page

Tags: php, wordpress

How to make a download page in Wordpress using PHP?

For example:

```
http://mywpsite.com/download.php?file=book.pdf
```

then the post result is: "Click here to download" with hyperlink like this: `http://mywpsite.com/files/book.pdf`

If the Url is

```
http://mywpsite.com/download.php?file=example.pdf
```

Then in the post will appear: "Click here to download" with hyperlink like this: `http://mywpsite.com/files/example.pdf`

Comment: Please provide examples of what you have already tried. We will be happy to help you find the solution.

Comment: Did you look for WordPress plugins that do what you ask?

Comment: i was try.. i duplicate with other name page.php in my theme and i access it but the function error.. i must include all php files?